# How to make a graph by float array and date array on a panel?

Tags: java, netbeans, charts

I have a function that returns an object, and it has a `Date[]` and `float[]`.

How do I make a line chart on a panel using those arrays?

I have read tutorials on how to make a chart but it is only for both integer on x-axis and y-axis.

The Date objects in the `Date[]` don't have a specific `time(00:00:00)`, it only has a `date(dd/MM/yyyy)`.

Also, I am using java and Netbeans with Jfreechart.

Here are some of the data in the array:

```
Date[]:
30/11/2016,
29/11/2016,
28/11/2016,
25/11/2016,
24/11/2016,
23/11/2016,
22/11/2016,
21/11/2016

float[]:
22789.77,
22737.07,
22830.57,
22723.45,
22608.49,
22676.69,
22678.07,
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could compute the number of days between two dates, and use this value .

Comment: @newbimyth Is it JavaFX?

Comment: @Nurzhan Yes it is java

Comment: @Berger can you make an example?

Answer (score 1):

If it is JavaFX (I still didn't get the full answer from you) and based on the standard example you can try something like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class LineChartSample extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        //defining the axes
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Date");
        //creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
                new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("My sample chart");
        //defining a series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("Test float data");
        //populating the series with data
        //And assumption has been made that your Date[] and float[] arrays are
        //of the same size and have one to one mapping.

        Date[] dates = ...  // here is your Date[] array
        float[] someData = ... // here is your float[] array

        for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(dates[i], someData[i]));
        }       
        Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I will not use Jfreechart, and do it all in the plotBtnActionPerformed method?

Comment: Can I create a several series and plot more lines on a same chart?

Comment: (To the question) Actually, it is just java, but I think I can create a new JavaFX class.

Comment: I check the imports see this  javax.swing.JPanel;

Comment: @newbimyth If I had a choice I would use JavaFX. Yes, you can create several series and plot them on the same chart. Look here for an example: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm